# Customize Apache Nifi Frontend

Tags: javascript, java, apache-nifi

I want to implement Apache Nifi on my webapp and i need to customize a little bit the UI to make it more compliant with my app.
I have some troubles in understanding where is the code of frontend in the Source2.0.0-M2 package you can download from the official website.

Where can I find the code?
Thank you in advance.

I have tried to change the js code in multiple folders but nothing has changed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.